# Find function by looking at inputs and outputs

Tags: analysis

By observing some system list of inputs and outputs is collected. Is there a general algorithm in mathematics for finding (approximate) polynomial function that will map inputs to outputs? It would be great if the procedure can be generalized to more than one variable.

Comment: What is the motivation for this problem? In particular, are you looking for a good model or an exact fit? These are not generally the same.

Comment: I guess this question is related to artificial intelligence. Also, as I know there are computer programs which evaluate the function by considering the inputs and outputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a polynomial, you can do [Lagrange interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_interpolation) to any desired order.  If you do one to a given order and the next point(s) fit, that would give you good confidence.